# Zoom using a slider with "React zoom pan pinch" library

Tags: reactjs, slider, zooming

I am using react-zoom-pan-pinch library. My requirement is I can zoom in/out using mouse wheel or a slider. Zooom in/out works fine using the above library. Now, onChange on of slider I want to call the library's internal zoom handler. I came across useControl which provides zoomIn and zoomOut function. In the [documentation](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/hooks-usecontrols--page), they have implemented zoom in and out using button. I want to customize it for slider. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to assign ref to `TransformWrapper` component. On onChange of the slider, call `transformWrapperRef.current.zoomIn()` or `transformWrapperRef.current.zoomOut()`. For example, if `newZoomValue > oldZoomValue` then call zoomIn() else zoomOut().
`const { instance, zoomIn, zoomOut, ...rest } = useControls()` works only inside `TransformWrapper`.